# Is there an established representation for the difference between two JSONs?

Tags: json, diff

Are there any established or existing formats or conventions for representing the diff between two JSON documents?

Lets say that two remote nodes (or a server/client) both have some data represented as a potentially complex JSON, the structure of which is not known before runtime.  One wants to send an update to the other, but without sending the whole state as one large JSON.  Instead, just the delta.  What would be a good way to represent the delta (or diff) between any two JSON documents?  They will likely be very similar (one small change), but might not be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSON documents are essentially trees, with leaves containing name/value pairs.

What you want to do is transmit a minimal tree delta: the smallest set of edits that converts one tree into another.

Computing tree deltas is a bit of an art, partly because it depends on the kinds of deltas you allow (just insert/delete leaf? swap subtrees? move subtree? duplicate subtree? rename names?  replace values?).  You also need to take into account semantic equivalences; if you commute the position of two subtrees, is the result semantically different?  (Your delta detector may see such a tree swap; the semantic identity check may eliminate it as not interesting).  If you duplicate a subtree, is the answer semantically different?  (I think for JSON the effective answer is "no").

You need something like a dynamic programming algorithm to determine such a minimal delta; you can take inspiration from [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) on strings.

This is a common issue of interest to programmers regarding source code.  Think of a JSON document as source code, and see the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/q/5779160/120163 for further discussion.

Comment: Nice, I had considered phrasing the question to ask about a "tree diff " or "tree delta" instead, but what I hadn't thought about yet was "the kinds of deltas you allow".

Comment: Great info. Just fyi: it seems the question you linked was deleted.

Comment: @Hassan:  Isn't SO such a nice place?  I won't replicate all the Q/A there. [You can still see this information if you are a 10K+ user].  This is a link to a SmartDifferencer family of tools my company provides: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer.  Yes, there is one for JSON.

Comment: But this accepted answer doesn't answer the question. The quesiton is about formats or conventions, not computing them.  There are lots of diff algorithms for text, but they can all use the same format, or different formats.

Comment: @user239558: Representations are about efficiently interpretable encodings of data you wish to represent.   To that end, you need to choose what the data you want to represent *is*.  In this case, the choice between a tree-based representation of delta and some that  differences is important.    Standard "diff" is the default for text-bas difference and you can apply it to JSON text.... just not very usefully, because JSON  represents trees of nested facts.  Pointing out the qualitatively different results is my main point here..   The tool is incidental.

Comment: @IraBaxter the representation was the question.  We can create a diff format for text based on an edit distance interpreter or operational transform. The operations exposed by the unix diff tool is one subset of possible text edit operations.  That's fine as an introduction, but there has to be real, existing examples of representations for tree diffs, so that's why I find the answer lacking.

Comment: @user239558:  Well, I didn't at the time, and still don't see any representations for tree diffs defined for JSON, which was OP's question.   The output of our SmartDiff tool *is* exactly such a representation.  It isn't the only one, because you can define arbitrary tree-editing operations and as long as they form a basis set, you can describe any tree changes using them.  We chose a modest set that we thought were intuitive to programmers looking at code:  delete(phrase), insert(phrase), replace(phrase), move(phrase), rename identifier inside subtree, and their compositions.

Comment: I have recently stumbled upon the following paper focusing on JSON similarity queries, using what they call JEDI (JSON Edit distance). The paper covers a lot of the intricacies of JSON comparisons (eg. ordered vs unordered structures) and formally defines lossless conversion to a tree representation, edit operations, ways to compute the minimal amount along with a number of filtering functions. The findings may be adaptable to this problem. See paper here: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3514221.3517850 Github: https://github.com/DatabaseGroup/jedi-experiments

Answer (score 6):

As Ira pointed out, there are some options along the lines of Levenshtein, but you'd be looking at serializing your object  and comparing it lexicographically which as Ira mentioned would not take into account the JSON-specific language diff that you are looking for (two trees could be identical JSON but very different by Levenshtein distance).  What you want is definitely the tree edit distance.

So to add some detail around the art of tree edit distance, the known algorithms used in this space are typically Zhang & Shasha or Klein for example and you can find python implementation of Zhang & Shasha.  These algorithms will obtain the minimum number of edits to convert one tree to another thus providing your diff.  However, they are somewhat slow O(n^2) at absolute best, so if you are comparing a large number of JSON objects or files, you will find yourself perfecting your golf game, doing the dishes, laundry, bathing your pets and other household miscellany.

And this is really where the art that Ira speaks of really is, because these kinds of algorithms are difficult and computationally expensive.  So what you may do is get creative.  One method is narrowing down the number of objects that *have* to be compared.  For example, why calculate edit distance between two JSON objects that are clearly more similar to an intermediate than to each other?  Don't calculate edit distance on objects that are identical via lexicographic comparison, If two objects are somewhat or dramatically different, perhaps forget the diff and just say there needs to be an outright replacement.

In order to apply the "art" of tree edit distance, that is saving yourself unnecessary CPU cycles, what you need is a way to provide metrics around what is meant by "somewhat similar" or "dramatically different".

To that end I've written an implementation of PQ-Gram tree edit distance *approximation* algorithm (http://www.vldb2005.org/program/paper/wed/p301-augsten.pdf) that you can find on github for use in Node.js or in the browser (https://github.com/hoonto/jqgram.git) based on the existing PyGram Python code (https://github.com/Sycondaman/PyGram).

PQ-Gram is much, much faster than true edit distance algorithms operating in O(n log n) time and O(n) space where n is the number of nodes.

So my recommendation is to use jqgram to very quickly get a feel for what you are looking at in terms of JSON object edit distance metrics.  Determine which JSON objects should be compared, versus just replaced, and then when you want the true distance to get the diff utilize Klein or Zhang & Shasha to get the actual diff.

Here's the jqgram JSON object tree edit distance approximation example taken straight out of the README for the jqgram implementation on github:

```
var jq = require("jqgram").jqgram;
var root1 = {
    "thelabel": "a",
    "thekids": [
        { "thelabel": "b",
        "thekids": [
            { "thelabel": "c" },
            { "thelabel": "d" }
        ]},
        { "thelabel": "e" },
        { "thelabel": "f" }
    ]
}

var root2 = {
    "name": "a",
    "kiddos": [
        { "name": "b",
        "kiddos": [
            { "name": "c" },
            { "name": "d" },
            { "name": "y" }
        ]},
        { "name": "e" },
        { "name": "x" }
    ]
}

jq.distance({
    root: root1,
    lfn: function(node){ return node.thelabel; },
    cfn: function(node){ return node.thekids; }
},{
    root: root2,
    lfn: function(node){ return node.name; },
    cfn: function(node){ return node.kiddos; }
},{ p:2, q:3, depth:10 },
function(result) {
    console.log(result.distance);
});
```

The lfn and cfn parameters specify how each JSON tree should determine the node label names and the children array for each tree root independently so that you can do fun things like compare JSON objects from different sources. All you need to do is provide those functions along with each root and jqgram will do the rest, calling your lfn and cfn provided functions to build out the trees.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposed Request For Comments, [RFC6902](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6902) ([archive at September 22, 2023](https://web.archive.org/web/20230922110109/https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6902)), titled "JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Patch" which appears to be a format for, as you requested, "representing the diff between two JSON documents", or rather for representing a sequence of basic operations which could transform one document into another.

The abstract states:

> JSON Patch defines a JSON document structure for expressing a
> sequence of operations to apply to a JavaScript Object Notation
> (JSON) document; it is suitable for use with the HTTP PATCH method.
> The "application/json-patch+json" media type is used to identify such
> patch documents.

In the introduction it states:

> This format is also potentially useful in other cases in which it is
> necessary to make partial updates to a JSON document or to a data
> structure that has similar constraints (i.e., they can be serialized
> as an object or an array using the JSON grammar).

It would be nice if this RFC was finalized, it looks useful to me. There are JavaScript and PHP libraries which use this RFC but I'll leave readers to find them.